# How to build a network application topography?

Tags: networking

My company has quite a few servers, and the applications that run on these servers are spread over many machines. Does anyone know of a program that will visualize these relationships in a MS Visio type manner? I looked into Spice-works, The Dude and a handful of other solutions, none will automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

You may look here:  http://visio.mvps.org/3rdparty.htm  and see if anything stands out.  Which applications are you referring to?  Another solution might be to create the relationships in SCOM (even with the eval copy) and then export that to Visio.  There'd be a learning curve for SCOM though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your hands on Visio 2000 Enterprise edition there is a built in tool for scanning networks and creating generated network diagrams.

They removed the tool in later versions in favor of third-party development in that sector, so you should check the link TheCleaner provided.

Answer (score 1):

[LanSurveyor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/LANsurveyor/faq.aspx) has an agent that will allow you to do a software inventory in addition to your network topology.  It's fairly spendy ($995 on sale, $1995 regularly) but they do have a demo version.  I've never tried it and don't know anyone who has.

You can also export to Visio

Answer (score 1):

I know of a suite that will do it if you have more money than you know what to do with :)

But seriously, I was under the impression (perhaps mistakenly) that [OpenNMS](http://opennms.org) or [Nagios](http://Nagios.org) could do something like this.